# How does browser combine two block elements?

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm confused by the calculation of elements. I know how the browser calculates [the size of the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214919/css-margin-calculation) but I don't know how the browser treat two elements or more. Say I have two block elements, which have paddings, margins, and borders. How does browser treat them when:

- one is on the left and another one is on the right?
- one is on the top and another one is on the bottom?
- one is inside another one?

Comment: What do you mean by, "how does it treat them"?

Comment: Surely this is easily discovered by coding the examples and viewing the rendered divs in the developer tools. Have you tried that?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English skill. I mean "teat them" is "put them in a right position".

Comment: I haven't heard of "developer tools" before, I tried and it can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the block elements do not have a set width.

Let's work backwards...

***One inside the other:*** all margins, borders and padding are cumulative. The *inner block* will expand to fill the *outer block* unless otherwise specified. And the *outer block* will expand to fill the width of its container unless otherwise specified. The width of the *inner block* will be calculated based on the overall container width minus the combined margins, borders and padding of both the *outer block* and *inner block* itself.

***One above the other:*** under normal circumstances the bottom margin of the *top block* and top margin of the *bottom block* will collapse so that your overall margin between the two is the greater of the two. Borders and padding remain unaltered. The 2 block elements will expand to take up the available width of their container unless otherwise specified.

***One beside the other:*** there are basically 2 ways to make this happen: by setting the ***display*** property of the elements to ***inline-block*** or by floating both elements. Since your question specifically states "block elements", I won't deal with inline-block. As far as floating goes, all margins, borders and padding remain unaltered. As already mentioned, block elements will take up the width of their container unless otherwise specified. This means they won't float next to one another unless you set the width of each so that the combined width + margin + border + padding of both blocks is equal to or less than the width of the container.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm... I think I understand except "one inside the other". Will the margin of the inner element and the padding of the outer element collapse? Many thanks.

Comment: No they won't. Check this for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, all elements have unique IDs or classes that's how the browser treats them all differently and you can add different styles to each one

```
<div id="container">
<div class="element1"></div>
<div class="element2"></div>
</div>
```

css styles

```
.element1 {
float:left;
background:red;
border-style: solid 2px
}
.element2{
float:right;
background:yellow;
border-style: solid 5px
}
```