# How are child margin calculated with respect to parent padding?

Tags: css, padding, margins

I am fairly versed with CSS box model however I always get confused with margins. For example, if a child div has a margin (say margin:10px;) and parent div has a padding(padding: 10px) then does the browser calculate the child margin space with respect to inner edge of parent div's padding or outer edge of parent div's padding.

In this [CSS Margin calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214919/css-margin-calculation) the answerer states: Margin - that's the space from the parent, it stacks with the parent's padding however he does not specify whether, it's  stacks with inner or outer edge of padding if specified on parent.

Thanks
dkjain

Comment: Inner edge of the parent element

Answer (score 0):

The margin of `child` div is stacked with the inner edge of the `parent` div's padding.

Comment: you mean inner edge of parent div's padding (if specified).